# How to authenticate or not from an Identity Server partial login

Tags: identityserver3

Our login process consists of a user providing a username and password then, once these are verified, having them choose an organisation to "log into." The combination of their user id and their chosen organisation makes up their "subject" claim.

I'm using Identity Server 3 and making good progress. I've created a User Service that verifies the username and password captured. If the user has only a single choice of organisation, the user service performs a Full Login. If the user has a choice or organisations the user service creates three claims (username, password and organisations choice) and performs a Partial Login redirecting to an organisation selection page (with the three claims and no subject). This works well (though I'd like to know if passing username and password via claims is sensible).

My confusion comes in the organisation selection controller:

1) If the user successfully selects an organisation I can use GetPartialLoginResumeUrlAsync to resume the login... but to make this work I believe I have to manually add the sub, name, idp, amr, and auth time claims using UpdatePartialLoginClaimsAsync. Is there an easier approach?

2) If the user is unsuccessful (perhaps they have taken a long time to select an organisation and now they have been disabled) how do I complete the process but return an error message? In the User Service I would have just created an AuthenticateResult with an error message.

Thank you

Piers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) If the user successfully selects an organisation I can use GetPartialLoginResumeUrlAsync to resume the login... but to make this work I believe I have to manually add the sub, name, idp, amr, and auth time claims using UpdatePartialLoginClaimsAsync. Is there an easier approach?

That's how it's expected to work: those are the required claims from the login process.

> 2) If the user is unsuccessful (perhaps they have taken a long time to select an organisation and now they have been disabled) how do I complete the process but return an error message? In the User Service I would have just created an AuthenticateResult with an error message.

Where do you want the error message? You're already on a custom page, so why not just show your error there?

Comment: Regarding 1)  I was wondering if there was an extension method that made it easier than creating the claims by hand... then I found it! Regarding 2), yes I can show the error myself, I just wasn't sure if this was the normal approach.